# BFT algorithm perfo

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

Understand that BFT algorithms are always prepared for the worst possible circumstances and pays a price for this in terms of speed.

Can one reasonably make the statement / assessment that non BFT algorithms such as Raft is more scalable in terms of TPS compared to other BFT algorithms such as Istanbul BFT (IBFT) and Tendermint?

Nathan Aw

Comment: It might be a good idea to also note the full name of the acronyms you use, to make this question more understandable for others. Also, what does 'scalable' mean here? It is a bit vague: 1) what is it that you wish to 'scale'? and 2) what is the resource/cost that should be kept low while scaling?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the feedback. Scalable means higher transaction per seconds (TPS). BFT: Byzantine Fault tolerance.

Comment: Please don't address requests for clarification by leaving a comment.  Instead, edit the question so it reads well and so future readers won't wonder the same thing.  We want people to be able to understand the question without having to read the comments.